# Rust Polars - `drop_nulls` equivalent but for `NaN`

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm working with a `DataFrame` that contains both `null` values and `NaN`, which I'm loading from a CSV file with `CsvReader`.

I would like to ignore any row which contains either a `null` or a `NaN` in any column. For example:

```
foo  | bar  | baz 
-------------------
1.0  | null | NaN
2.3  | 34.5 | 0.0
null | 4.5  | 5.0
NaN  | 3.0  | 4.0
```

should become

```
foo  | bar  | baz 
-------------------
2.3  | 34.5 | 0.0
```

I'm able to drop the `null` values with:

```rust
let without_nulls = df
  .lazy()
  .drop_nulls::<String>(None);
```

But there is no equivalent for `NaN`. Looking through the polars docs, I found [this function](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.drop_nans), which seems to suggest it's possible, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to achieve it.

I believe I could create a large filter with `col("col_1").neq(f64::NAN).and(col("col_2").neq(f64::NAN))` etc., but I'd rather avoid doing this since I have lots of columns.

This seems like such a common task, I'm surprised that there isn't an obvious way to do it. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use `.neq(f64::NAN)` anyway, as even NaN is not equal to itself (so they'd be kept). Does `df.lazy().filter(all().is_not_nan())` work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [@BallpointBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496433/ballpointben) to the original question did not work for me, but came quite close; instead of `df.lazy().filter(all().is_not_nan())`, use `df.lazy().filter(all_horizontal([all().is_not_nan()]))`:

```
use polars::{lazy::dsl::all_horizontal, prelude::*};

fn main() -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    let df = df!(
        "foo" => &[Some(1.0), Some(2.3), None, Some(f64::NAN)],
        "bar" => [None, Some(34.5), Some(4.5), Some(3.0)],
        "baz" => [f64::NAN, 0.0, 5.0, 4.0]
    )?;

    println!("{:?}", df);
    // ┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
    // │ foo  ┆ bar  ┆ baz │
    // │ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
    // │ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64 │
    // ╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
    // │ 1.0  ┆ null ┆ NaN │
    // │ 2.3  ┆ 34.5 ┆ 0.0 │
    // │ null ┆ 4.5  ┆ 5.0 │
    // │ NaN  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 4.0 │
    // └──────┴──────┴─────┘

    let without_nulls = df
        .lazy()
        .drop_nulls(None)
        .filter(all_horizontal([all().is_not_nan()]))
        .collect()?;

    println!("{:?}", without_nulls);
    // ┌─────┬──────┬─────┐
    // │ foo ┆ bar  ┆ baz │
    // │ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
    // │ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64 │
    // ╞═════╪══════╪═════╡
    // │ 2.3 ┆ 34.5 ┆ 0.0 │
    // └─────┴──────┴─────┘

    Ok(())
}
```